# Android: AutoCompleteTextView as Collapsable Action View focus issues

Tags: android

Hi so for my needs i cannot use SearchView  because i am filtering an array list that contains some custom object plus this AutoCompleteTextView is embedded into the toolbar as a menu item

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchFoodMenuItem"
    android:title="@string/generic.search"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/view_search_food_auto_complete"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    />
```

I wish to mimic the behaviour of searchview in these cases:

1. Clicking on the icon puts the auto complete text view in focus and brings up the key board (I have kind of achieved this but i have a small issue that i need help with)
2. While the auto complete text view is in focus, clicking anywhere else on the screen that is not the keyboard will remove the focus of the auto complete text view rather than passing the touch to the view that was pressed.

Some code

So i wrote my own extension of the AutoCompleteTextView.

Here is some key snippets

The part below simply closes / opens the keyboard when the focus of the view has changed. This also includes clicking on it and pressing back on the soft keyboard.

```
@Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        if (focused) {
            inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, 0);
        } else {
            setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

 @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        requestFocus();
        return super.performClick();
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            clearFocus();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Below is the code which puts the view into focus when the menu item is expanded

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(mSearchFoodMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                mSearchFoodInputField.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        DebugUtils.Log("onMenuItemActionExpand");
                        mSearchFoodInputField.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
               return true;
           }
       });
```

The above works the first time, i.e. if i click on the menu item, the auto complete text view becomes focused and the key board appears. All is well, but if i collapse this menu item and do it again, it no longer becomes focused and i am not sure why.

**More reasons I am not using SearchView**

The main reason I do not want to use it is because I want to display search suggestions based on my array list of objects. My understanding of the API tells me that search view can only do this on a database Cursor (which I am not using)

**Search view code**

The menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/generic.search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

In onCreateOptionsMenu

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.piece_discover_menu, menu);
        mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchMenuItem);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mFoodSearchAdapter); 
    }
```

Below is what i tried

I made a searchable config

Note i tried with and without completetionThreshold

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint=“@string/search_hint”
   android:searchSuggestThreshold=“1”
 android:completionThreshold=“1”
</searchable>
```

Me applying the search config

Note this was declared between the application tags

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

Me adding the search manager

```
     SearchManager searchManager =
               (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
 mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(
          searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
```

Comment: i dont understand the reason for not using a std SearchView

Comment: @pskink Hi I added some more reasons why I do not use search view at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: 1) you dont need a `ContentProvider` + `searchable`s for that: you could use `setSuggestionsAdapter(CursorAdapter adapter)` 2) you can always use `MatrixCursor` when you need `Cursor` interface: `mc.newRow().add(...).add(...)....`

Comment: @pskink interesting, so you are saying that I have to convert my array list to a MaxtrixCursor in order to use it for the CursorAdapter to get suggestions? Do you have an example of how It looks? i.e. does the suggestions appear like a auto complete text view?

Comment: call `setSuggestionsAdapter` with an adapter taken for example from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. I found this link too http://ramannanda.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/android-searchview-integration-with.html

Comment: @pskink So does the CursorAdapter implement filterable? How does the auto complete query the data

Comment: yes `CursorAdapter` implements `Filterable`, you can filter things out via `FilterQueryProvider` or directly by overiding `runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint)` try to add the above code snippet to `onCreate` and add some `Log.d` calls in `runQuery`

Comment: @pskink thanks i implemented it

Comment: @pskink However the search view does not do point number 2. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @pskink hi do you know how to set the search threshold with this method? I use a searchable config but it does not work always defaults to 2 characters

Comment: how do you use your SearchView?  where is your code?

Comment: @pskink Sorry for the delay, i added all the code

Comment: Log.d what `searchManager.getSearchableInfo()` returns

Comment: @pskink When i called toString after getSeachableInfo, turns out its null and i get a null pointer. So that whole line searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()) gives me null

Comment: searchable.xml has to have `android:label`, not `android:hint`, for example: android:label="@string/search_label" android:searchSuggestThreshold="1"

Comment: @pskink Just tried it, same problems

Comment: do you have action SEARCH in your <intent-filter> tag?

Comment: @pskink No. I did not use that because i do not have a separate search activity but i am using fragments to 1 activity

Comment: reading from sources the only way to set the threshold is via searchable.xml so you have to deal with it

Comment: @pskink same problem :(

Comment: so search the inet, why it is null...

Comment: @pskink Been searching for a while nothing so far. I might just go back to AutoCompleteTextView because i had it working on 1 threshold on that

Comment: so use ACTV, set the same Adapter for filtering purposes

Comment: @pskink yeah but i will have the original problem to solve (see title) :P

Comment: ok so find why getSearchableInfo() is null, i just tried it and my getSearchableInfo() != null

Comment: Would it be ok for you the post the code? So i can compare? I've been looking cant see whats wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88724/discussion-between-john-carter-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink Would it be ok for you the post the code? So i can compare? I've been looking cant see whats wrong

Comment: http://codeshare.io/MgANv

Comment: @pskink Thanks. Will try and compare soon. Out of curiosity, is it working? The 1 character threshold for search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to pskink , I used a search view instead. To get suggestions like the AutoCompleteTextView i used a cursorAdapter. However if like me you had an array list of some Java object, you need to convert it to a Cursor as follows.

```
 public static final String[] COLUMNS = new String[]{"_id","foodName","foodReference"};

 public static final int ID_INDEX = 0, FOOD_NAME_INDEX = 1, FOOD_REFERENCE_INDEX = 2;

  private MatrixCursor convertToCursor (ArrayList<Food> foods){
        MatrixCursor cursor =  new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);
        for(Food food : foods){
            String[]row = new String[COLUMNS.length];
            row[ID_INDEX] = Integer.toString(mFoods.indexOf(food));
            row[FOOD_NAME_INDEX] = food.getName();
            row[FOOD_REFERENCE_INDEX] = food.getReferenceNumber();
            cursor.addRow(row);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: personally i prefer: `cursor.newRow().add(id++).add(foof.getName()).add(food.getReferenceNumber())`